# Can I associate a change set with a work item after it has been delivered?

Tags: rtc

If I deliver a change set to a stream and not associate it with a work item can the change set be associated with a work item after it has been delivered ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

The changeset itself is closed upon delivery to the stream.
But its associated work-item(s) is not: you can add or remove one or several work-items in association with the delivered changeset.

That being said, I have a special hook which makes that association mandatory on deliver: ie, you cannot deliver without having first associated your change set first to a Work Item.

I am not sure if that hook is a custom one for my organization, but here is where you can check if it is there:

It is in the Project  Area administration, under

```
Team Configuration / 
Operation Behavior / 
Source Control / 
Deliver (client) / 
Preconditions and follow-up actions are configured for this operation / 
Require Work Items and comments
```

[image: Require Work Item hook]

Comment: thanks, I like the idea of a hook for force the association. Is this difficult to setup, can you add a link on how to do this ?

Comment: @user470184 I have edited my answer to add and illustrate the hook.