# What is the difference between the two deliver options in 'Operation Behaviour' in RTC?

Tags: rtc

At 'Project Area' level on RTC under 'Team Configuration' -> 'Operation Behaviour' there are two deliver options :

[image]

What is the differnence between the two ? Are they both not delivering to the server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are for hooks:

- executed on the client, that is *before* the deliver,
- executed on the server, that is at the reception of the deliver.

It is on the client side, for instance, that I set the hook requiring that a Work Item is associated to a change set before said change set can be delivered (as illustrated in your previous question "[Can I associate a change set with a work item after it has been delivered?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13360576/6309)").
I could check it on the server, but why use network traffic if the deliver is rejected anyway?

More precisely, As mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/75190/source-control-delivery-approval/75199):

> In general, you want all preconditions to run on the server, so the server (including the web server) can ensure those preconditions have been executed.
>
> **But there are some preconditions that must be run on the client, namely those that need to look at the local state of the client**.
>   This is illustrated by the list of predefined preconditions.
>   In particular, most of these preconditions refer to the build/compile state of the workspace (information not available on the server), such as: "`prohibit unused imports`" and "`prohibit workspace errors`".
>
> Note that there are three client-side preconditions that do not require client-side information ("`require work item approval`", "`require work item and comments`", "`descriptive change sets`").
>   **These are included for backward compatibility, since they were made available in the first release of RTC, but have since then made available as server-side preconditions as well**, so you should always use the server-side form of them.
>   I've submitted [work item 209427](https://jazz.net/jazz/web/projects/Rational%20Team%20Concert#action=com.ibm.team.workitem.viewWorkItem&id=209427) to get these client-side preconditions marked as "deprecated" with a pointer to the server-side preconditions that replace them.

Comment: So the only difference is when/where the condition takes place, at the client or server ? Why even differentiate this, should it not always occur at the server, a possible reason is to reduce server load ?

Comment: @user470184 It is to reduce the network traffic. No need to deliver something if the conditions are not met? And yet, the example I use would be better set on the server. See my edited answer.